# Giving access to Jekins API calls for a specific IP

Tags: jenkins

I have my Jenkins server setup to authenticate from [GitHub](https://github.com/) with the [OAuth](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+OAuth+Plugin) plugin. This works great as all the users of this are setup on GitHub an all part of the same Organization.

The part that I'm having issue with is I need to have access to the Jenkins restful API from another computer (specifically a node server) to get some information. This server needs access directly without a GitHub account. How can I go about granting access by IP or some other method?

On the node side I'm looking to use [node-jenkins](https://github.com/silas/node-jenkins).

The error I'm getting is:

```
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
```

So how do I let an anonymous user, from a specific IP, access the API?

Comment: What are you trying to get from Jenkins or to the node server?

Comment: list of jobs and build information from the jerkins API.

Comment: I would make another user on the system and create an app token for it

Comment: @Justin808 i am trying to hit the jenkins api using jenkins_exporter(prometheus). I am also facing the same issue. Can you please let me know how did you solve the issue.